# Weird bone movement

Tags: rigging

I am trying to rig a character. I'm even following a tutorial on how to do it. But I noticed my mesh doing something that is not seemingly a problem in the tutorial video. I've experimented with a lot of different weights and in different places, but my mesh always makes an unnatural looking crease whenever it moves. I would like to use point weighting to rig the mesh with. The picture below is what happens when the neck bends, though the all the bones in the body are doing this.
[image]

Thank everybody in advance, thank you!

Comment: maybe your mesh is high-poly and the separation between the bone influence is too sharp, so when you bend a bone you clearly see the frontier between a vertex group and another?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond to my question! Let me try messing with where the joint of the bone is. In the tutorial, he said to put the joint of the bone between three edge loops, so I will try putting in between faces now.

Comment: Huh... I guess my mesh really was more high poly than I thought... I would not have figured that out on my own. So thank you again moonboots! Godbless!